# nox not able to to find python 3.7 interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, nox

I am trying to contribute to open source repo. And I realize that my test is failing on python 3.7 interpreter, it passing in 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10.  I am trying to run this locally so I could fix it.

However, when I am trying to run it. it shows me following error.

```
❯ nox -R -s unit-3.7 -- -k test_load_table_from_dataframe_w_datatype_mismatch
nox > Running session unit-3.7
nox > Missing interpreters will error by default on CI systems.
nox > Session unit-3.7 skipped: Python interpreter 3.7 not found.
```

I have python 3.7 installed using `pyenv`

```
❯ pyenv versions
  system
  3.7.10
* 3.7.12 (set by /Users/fki/Documents/git/python-bigquery/.python-version)
  3.8.10
  3.8.10/envs/airflow-env
  3.8.18
  airflow-env --> /Users/fki/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/envs/airflow-env
```

I have no issues running tests on python 3.10 even though it's not installed.

```
❯ nox -R -s unit-3.10 -- -k test_load_table_from_dataframe_w_datatype_mismatch
nox > Running session unit-3.10
nox > Re-using existing virtual environment at .nox/unit-3-10.
nox > py.test --quiet --cov=google/cloud/bigquery --cov=tests/unit --cov-append --cov-config=.coveragerc --cov-report= --cov-fail-under=0 --capture=tee-sys tests/unit -k test_load_table_from_dataframe_w_datatype_mismatch
.                                                                                                                                                                                                                      [100%]
====================================================================================================== warnings summary ======================================================================================================
.nox/unit-3-10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/mark/structures.py:357
  /Users/fki/Documents/git/python-bigquery/.nox/unit-3-10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/mark/structures.py:357: PytestRemovedIn9Warning: Marks applied to fixtures have no effect
  See docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#applying-a-mark-to-a-fixture-function
    store_mark(func, self.mark)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
1 passed, 2291 deselected, 1 warning in 2.22s
nox > Session unit-3.10 was successful.
```

could someone explain, from where nox is taking interpreter ?

Comment: Did you activate all the relevant pyenv environments? Like this:
```
pyenv global 3.7.10 3.8.10 3.9 3.10
```
(see: https://github.com/wntrblm/nox/issues/252)

Comment: @mudskipper perfect. that resolved the issue. However, I am still confused on from where it's taking 3.10, as it's clearly not in pyenv.

Comment: Similar to `tox`, nox creates deletes and creates virtualenvs on the fly, so it's not necessary to already have a particular one. See: "https://nox.thea.codes/en/stable/usage.html#re-using-virtualenvs".

Comment: weird. but that means it's suppose to work for `python 3.7` as well. however didn't until I ran the command you gave me.

Comment: This may be related to the github issue I linked to. I'm not really familiar with `nox` (used `tox` in the past), so don't know the answer, but that issue contains a detailed analysis.